# QML singleton declaration via qt_add_qml_module()

Tags: qml, singleton, qt6

QML singleton's properties undefined if QML file placed in subdirectory e.g "qml" (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qml/Style.qml). When it placed in project root dir everything works fine.

thats module declaration:

```
set_source_files_properties(Style.qml PROPERTIES
  QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE TRUE
)

qt_add_qml_module(untitled
    URI untitled
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
      qml/main.qml
      qml/Style.qml
)
```

Style.qml is QML singleton (`pragma Singleton`)

Qt 6.4.2

Comment: Did you try to add the full path here as well? 

`set_source_files_properties(qml/Style.qml ...)`

Comment: @iam_peter tried - it has no effect